# worklight - Cannot use WL.Client.getUserInfo("LDAPRealm", "userId") to get information after refresh page with LDAPLoginModule

Tags: ldap, ibm-mobilefirst

I used the LDAPLoginModule sample app, and I found that I can't use `WL.Client.getUserInfo("LDAPRealm", "userId")` to get any login user information after refresh page, is that right? if it is, how can I get user information after refresh page?

Comment: Explain what do you mean by "refresh page"? Provide your code. All of it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm just a green hands of worklight, I visit this LDAPLoginModule sample app through worklightconsole in a browser like chrome, everything seems correct after I login, I can get user ID or isUserAuthenticated by **WL.Client.getUserInfo**, but after I refresh page, just like click refresh button in browser or press F5,  I can't get active user by **WL.Client.getUserInfo** any more. is that right? or you just mean that there is no "refresh" in mobilephone?

Comment: There is indeed no refersh in your mobile app, so I am not sure how valid the scenario would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no refresh *button* in a mobile app, so your scenario does not appear valid to me (if I understand it correctly). If you want to programmatically trigger a reload, you can use the `WL.Client.realoadApp` API method.